# Is it possible to show a webpage inside of an AIR app?

Tags: flash, air

Is it possible to show a webpage inside of an AIR app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.  use `HTMLLoader`.  ([see adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_02.html))